# Enable disabled umbraco user in user control

Tags: c#, umbraco

Umbraco v 4.11.10

I am working with Umbraco users from a user control and I want to be able to manage which members should be allowed to use Umbraco.

I can easily create (User.MakeNew) and disable (User.Disable()) an Umbraco user, but I am looking for a way to reactivate disabled users in code. Isn't it possible ??

btw: Yes I know it's an old version, but that's how it is.

Best regards, Martin

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
var userService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService;
var newUserModel = userService.GetUserById(userId);
if (newUserModel != null)
{
    newUserModel.IsLockedOut = false;
    userService.Save(newUserModel, false);
}
```

User disables in IsLockedOut property.